# Как решить ошибку 'An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent' error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой: `An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.`

Приложение на `nuxt(2.15.8)`, `vue(2.6.14)`

Ошибка возникает, когда пытаюсь повторно открыть окно аутентификации.

*Более подробно*: нажимаю на кнопку "Войти", открывается попап, закрываю попап, снова нажимаю на кнопку "Войти", возникает ошибка и окно не открывается.

Вот метод компонента (`this.authChoicePopup` это состояние компонента, изначально = `null`)

```
 handlePopupButton () {
  if (this.authChoicePopup && !this.authChoicePopup.closed) {
    this.authChoicePopup.close()
  }

  const url = '/login'

  const popupOptions = {
    resizable: 'yes',
    scrollbars: 'no',
    toolbar: 'yes',
    menubar: 'yes',
    location: 'no',
    directories: 'no',
    status: 'yes',
    width: Math.min(800, screen.availWidth),
    height: Math.min(800, screen.availHeight)
  }

  popupOptions.left = Math.max(0, (window.screenX + (window.innerWidth - popupOptions.width) / 2))
  popupOptions.top = Math.max(0, (window.screenY + (window.innerHeight - popupOptions.height) / 2))

  const popupFeatureParts = []
  for (const propName in popupOptions) {
    popupFeatureParts.push(propName + '=' + popupOptions[propName])
  }
  const popupFeature = popupFeatureParts.join(',')

  this.authChoicePopup = window.open(url, 'auth_popup', popupFeature)
  this.authChoicePopup.focus()
}
```

Если в методе убрать условие

```
  if (this.authChoicePopup && !this.authChoicePopup.closed) {
    this.authChoicePopup.close()
  }
```

то окно открывается и можно авторизоваться, НО ошибка всё равно возникает. Как это исправить?